# I use Simply Fortran, but cannot include modules there

Tags: error-handling, fortran, gfortran

I have written the following Fortran Code in the System called "Simply Fortran":

```
program math2 
use prec, only: print_kind_info
implicit none
call print_kind_info
end program math2

module prec

 implicit none
 integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(P=10,R=30) 
 integer, parameter :: sp = selected_real_kind(P=5,R=15)
 integer, parameter :: dp_alt = kind(0.d0)
 public :: dp, sp, print_kind_info
 private 

contains

! Subroutine comes here

subroutine print_kind_info()
real(sp) :: sing_prec
real(dp) :: double_prec

print*,'Single precision is kind ',sp
print*,'Double precision is kind ',dp
print*,'Kind of double precision number is ',dp_alt

end subroutine print_kind_info

end module prec
```

However, the module which I call 'prec' is not found. More precisely, the error message is the following:

```
 use prec, only: print_kind_info
    1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'prec.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Error(E42): Last command making (build\prec.o) returned a bad status
Error(E02): Make execution terminated

* Failed *
```

What I have to do that the module (see above code) is recognized properly? It is recognized in File Outline, but it is not inside the "module" folder. And I really don't have a plan here what to do. Moreover I have no experience with the Makefile environment (this BASHrc-like things I am not familar with).

Answer (score 0):

Simply said: The problem is that the compiler doesn't know the module `prec.mod` at is defined after the main program but is used already in the main program.

So first define the module and after that the main program.

Better would be to place the module in a separate files and the main program in another file and compile these (in the right order) and link everything together.